# Android R.java ID switch always gives default

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I am using a Java switch statement to assign different values to a variable based on the id of the button that called it.

The problem is that it always evaluates to the detail.

I think the error might be in how I am getting the Id (the `R.java` bit), but I have done some internet research, and can't find the 'proper' way of doing it.

This is my code (the `-99` and `23` are there so it was obvious if it wasn't working)

```
public void rootMe(View v){

 /* I got rid of some code here so it was shorter */

    int mult = -99;

    int buttonId = v.getId();

    switch(buttonId)
    {
    case R.id.root2:
        mult = 1/2;
    case R.id.root3:
        mult = 1/3;
    case R.id.root4:
        mult = 1/4;
    case R.id.root5:
        mult = 1/5;
    case R.id.root6:
        mult = 1/6;
    default:
        mult = 23;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `swicth` construct, once a `case` has been reached, the code below that `case` will be executed -- even if there is another `case` statement.

If you want the execution to stop *(to exit the `switch` construct)*, you must use a `break` statement ; most probably at the end of each one of your `case` blocks :

```
switch(buttonId)
{
    case R.id.root2:
        mult = 1/2;
        break;
    case R.id.root3:
        mult = 1/3;
        break;
    case R.id.root4:
        mult = 1/4;
        break;
    case R.id.root5:
        mult = 1/5;
        break;
    case R.id.root6:
        mult = 1/6;
        break;
    default:
        mult = 23;
        break;
}
```

This way, when the code that corresponds to a `case` statement is executed, it will no longer execute the code that corresponds to the following `case`s statements, and exit the `switch` construct.

Note that this is not android-specific : it's just the way the `switch` statement works in JAVA ; see for exemple : [**The `switch` Statement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't `break`. You must put a break statement after every case so it doesn't continue executing and testing for cases. . .

```
switch(buttonId)
    {
    case R.id.root2:
        mult = 1/2;
        break;
    case R.id.root3:
        mult = 1/3;
        break;
    case R.id.root4:
        mult = 1/4;
        break;
    case R.id.root5:
        mult = 1/5;
        break;
    case R.id.root6:
        mult = 1/6;
        break;
    default:
        mult = 23;
    }
```

Read more here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article here you probably should look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html